# Spring cloud gateway response never arrives

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I was trying out Spring Cloud Gateway (Finchley.M5). Then I built up this simple project based on Springboot 2 (2.0.0.M7):

1. Eureka
2. Spring Cloud Gateway
3. A service (WebFlux `@RestController`)

When asking the service directly, the response arrives as expected:

[image]

But when I try to ask for the service through the Gateway, the service receives the request (I printed a message to the console) but the response never get back to the client:

[image]

The repo with the project is over here: https://github.com/julianobrasil/spring-gateway-test

**[EDIT 1]:** So you don't have to clone the above repo to see what is going on with the code, here it is:

### 1 - Gateway

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/service/**")
                    .rewritePath("/service/(?<path>.*)", "/${path}")
                    .uri("lb://mySimpleService"))
            .build();
  }
}
```

### 2 - Service Controller

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/test")
  Mono<String> getHello() {
    System.out.println("I received a connection request");
    return Mono.just("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

**[EDIT 2]:** Someone on the Spring Cloud team has cloned my repo and tested it. And reported it worked just fine. Apparently, the test was made in a Linux system (I'm running it on a windows 10 machine).

Comment: check if that Spring Cloud M5 [sample application code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/tree/master/spring-cloud-gateway-sample) will help. Especially [the config class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-sample/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/sample/GatewaySampleApplication.java)

Comment: @DevDio, actually, someone on the spring cloud project repo tested my code and told me it worked fine in his system (apparently, a linux machine). I'm gonna remove my .m2 directory and see whether I can figure out what the problem is (I'm running it in a Windows 10 machine)

Comment: @DevDio, for now I don't have a single clue about what's happening. I've removed my .m2 directory, mvn-clean-install'ed it and nothing. The response simply doesn't get back to the client. I'd appreciate if you could clone my repo, test it on your system and post the results here along with your configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the real problem was a typical windows world problem: antivirus. Kaspersky was bloking the http response. To whom it may concern:

[image]